# How would I go about converting a string with a two digit number to int without using if statements, character arrays, apstrings, or atoi?

Tags: c++, string, numbers, integer, converters

As the question says, it can't use if statements, character arrays, apstrings, or atois. We've only had 5 classes, so we haven't done anything too complicated and I'm completely lost. Thank you for your help!

Comment: you should at least mention the programming language, also tag it

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what language you're talking about and platform if appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that the string always contains two characters that are digits, you can just get the character codes and convert to the digit value, then put them together to a number.

Example:

```
int number = (str[0] - '0') * 10 + (str[1] - '0');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I forgot to mention that it's for C++, not for C#.

Comment: The code to do that in C++ happens to be identical to C#, so you can accept this answer.

Comment: Code works fine, but isn't this an array? Or am I just being completely wrong here.

Comment: @jjesh: A string is just an array of characters, and the bracket syntax is just another way of accessing items using a pointer anyway. You can use `*str` and `*(str+1)` to access the first and second characters using the string pointer, but that is just a syntactic difference, the generated code is identical to the bracket syntax.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 to the rescue!

```
try {
  int i = std::stoi(str);
} catch (std::exception const&) {
  // Invalid conversion
}
```

<sup>(Probably cheating if this is an exercise...but you only excluded `atoi`.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* str = "97";

int number = (str[0] - '0') * 10 + (str[1] - '0');
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. But isn't that an array?

Comment: in C, a string is a special kind of an array of characters, so anything you can do on an array, you can do on a string.

Answer (score -1):

no if, no array, no atoi, but ugly:

```
int ConvertToInt(const string &str)
{
    return
        str == "99" ? 99 :
        str == "98" ? 98 :
        str == "97" ? 97 :
        str == "96" ? 96 :
        str == "95" ? 95 :
        str == "94" ? 94 :
        str == "93" ? 93 :
        str == "92" ? 92 :
        str == "91" ? 91 :
        str == "90" ? 90 :
        str == "89" ? 89 :
        str == "88" ? 88 :
        str == "87" ? 87 :
        str == "86" ? 86 :
        str == "85" ? 85 :
        str == "84" ? 84 :
        str == "83" ? 83 :
        str == "82" ? 82 :
        str == "81" ? 81 :
        str == "80" ? 80 :
        str == "79" ? 79 :
        str == "78" ? 78 :
        str == "77" ? 77 :
        str == "76" ? 76 :
        str == "75" ? 75 :
        str == "74" ? 74 :
        str == "73" ? 73 :
        str == "72" ? 72 :
        str == "71" ? 71 :
        str == "70" ? 70 :
        str == "69" ? 69 :
        str == "68" ? 68 :
        str == "67" ? 67 :
        str == "66" ? 66 :
        str == "65" ? 65 :
        str == "64" ? 64 :
        str == "63" ? 63 :
        str == "62" ? 62 :
        str == "61" ? 61 :
        str == "60" ? 60 :
        str == "59" ? 59 :
        str == "58" ? 58 :
        str == "57" ? 57 :
        str == "56" ? 56 :
        str == "55" ? 55 :
        str == "54" ? 54 :
        str == "53" ? 53 :
        str == "52" ? 52 :
        str == "51" ? 51 :
        str == "50" ? 50 :
        str == "49" ? 49 :
        str == "48" ? 48 :
        str == "47" ? 47 :
        str == "46" ? 46 :
        str == "45" ? 45 :
        str == "44" ? 44 :
        str == "43" ? 43 :
        str == "42" ? 42 :
        str == "41" ? 41 :
        str == "40" ? 40 :
        str == "39" ? 39 :
        str == "38" ? 38 :
        str == "37" ? 37 :
        str == "36" ? 36 :
        str == "35" ? 35 :
        str == "34" ? 34 :
        str == "33" ? 33 :
        str == "32" ? 32 :
        str == "31" ? 31 :
        str == "30" ? 30 :
        str == "29" ? 29 :
        str == "28" ? 28 :
        str == "27" ? 27 :
        str == "26" ? 26 :
        str == "25" ? 25 :
        str == "24" ? 24 :
        str == "23" ? 23 :
        str == "22" ? 22 :
        str == "21" ? 21 :
        str == "20" ? 20 :
        str == "19" ? 19 :
        str == "18" ? 18 :
        str == "17" ? 17 :
        str == "16" ? 16 :
        str == "15" ? 15 :
        str == "14" ? 14 :
        str == "13" ? 13 :
        str == "12" ? 12 :
        str == "11" ? 11 :
        str == "10" ? 10 :
        str == "09" ? 9 :
        str == "08" ? 8 :
        str == "07" ? 7 :
        str == "06" ? 6 :
        str == "05" ? 5 :
        str == "04" ? 4 :
        str == "03" ? 3 :
        str == "02" ? 2 :
        str == "01" ? 1 :
        str == "00" ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Comment: you can't use == like that with C/C++

Comment: if you use std::string, you can use == like that